# why can't this Uniform sampler2D be found?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to texture a quad in OpenGL and keep getting -1 when getting the uniform location.

EDIT: Without the Uniform code, it renders just fine(minus the texture ofc).
here's the code:

texture binding code;

```
m_renderer.prepare();
m_colorProgram.start();
// Sets the active texture to '0'.
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture.id);
GLint samplerLoc = m_colorProgram.getUniformLocation("mySampler");
// Tells OGl that we are using the active texture '0' as stated above.
glUniform1i(samplerLoc, 0);

m_renderer.render(m_model);

// Always unbind
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
m_colorProgram.stop();
```

m_colorProgram.getUniformLocation:

```
GLint GLSLProgram::getUniformLocation ( const std::string uniformName )
{
    GLint location = glGetUniformLocation ( m_programID, "size" );
    if ( location == (GLint)GL_INVALID_INDEX ) {
        fatal_error ( "Uniform '" + uniformName + "' could not be found!" );
    }
    return location;
}
```

vert shader:

```
#version 130
// super simple shader program
in vec3 vertexPositon;
in vec4 vertexColor;
in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec4 fragColor;
out vec2 fragUV;

void main(){

    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPositon,1.0);

    fragColor = vertexColor;
    fragUV = vertexUV;

}
```

frag shader:

```
#version 130
in vec4 fragColor;
in vec2 fragUV;
uniform sampler2D mySampler;
out vec4 color;
void main() 
{
    vec4 texColor = texture( mySampler, fragUV );
    color = texColor * fragColor;
}
```

Most of the solutions I've found online seem to indicate that the Uniform is is being cut out because it is not being used, however, as you can see, it IS being used, and yet still is returning a -1.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: can you post the code where you attach the shader?

Comment: Please also add the vertex shader.

Comment: @AbdulAhad Sure I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had hardcoded a string without realizing it in `glGetUniform`